# Sorting map by LocalDate

Tags: scala

I have the following map:

```
var result = collection.mutable.Map[LocalDate,String]
```

I need to sort it by LocalDate, this doesn't work, as I get the following compilation error: `missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) ⇒ x$1._1.isAfter(((x$2) ⇒ x$2._1)))`:

```
result.toSeq.sortWith(_._1.isAfter(_._1))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Be more explicit.

Comment: I get the following compilation error: `missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) ⇒ x$1._1.isAfter(((x$2) ⇒ x$2._1)))`

Comment: You should put that error in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either of these will compile.

```
result.toSeq.sortWith(_._1 isAfter _._1)
// or
result.toSeq.sortWith((a,b) => a._1.isAfter(b._1))
```

Putting the passed-parameter underscore `_` inside inner parentheses changes its meaning.